# Showing that $\displaystyle\prod_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} = 0$ for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

How can I show that
$$\displaystyle\prod_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} = 0$$ when $x$ is a positive real number ?

Comment: An infinite product $\prod_n a_n$ converges to $0$ whenever the infinite sum $\sum_n \log (a_n)$ diverges to $- \infty$. This is equivalent to show that $\sum_n (a_n-1)$ diverges to $- \infty$. Now, $\sum_n -\frac{1}{2+nx}$ behaves like an harmonic series, hence it diverges to $- \infty$.

Comment: You don't want "Limit of" at the beginning of your title.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \prod_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} = 0$$

Proof:

$$\frac{1+kx}{2+kx}=1+\frac{-1}{2+kx} \leqslant\exp \left( \frac{-1}{2+kx} \right) \leqslant \exp \left( \frac{-x^{-1}}{k} \right)$$

So,

$$ \prod_{k = 1}^{N} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} \leqslant \prod_{k = 1}^{N} \exp \left( \frac{-x^{-1}}{k} \right) = \exp(-x^{-1}H_N)$$

where $H_N$ is the $N^{th}$ harmonic number.

Using the simple estimate $H_N > \log N$, we have that

$$\prod_{k = 0}^{N} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} \le \frac{1}{2} \exp(-x^{-1}\log N)=\frac{1}{2N^{x^{-1}}}\to 0$$

Comment: What I don't understand is that you say : "$\displaystyle\prod_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} = 0 \leq exp(-x^{-1}H_n)$ and then $H_n < logN$ but this two inequalities don't necesseraly imply : $\displaystyle\prod_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1+kx}{2+kx} \leq exp(-x^{-1} log N)$

Comment: I said that $H_N > \log N$, which *does* give the desired implication. I'm also dealing with finite products.